# React-native app failed to build suddenly

Tags: react-native, android-studio

My app is giving me this huge block of error when I run 'react-native run-android'.

I'm sorry but I don't remember what/when/how things went wrong. Here are some things I remember doing since the last time it was working:

1. Tried to open the android project in Android Studio to check if I should update the gradle (I didn't) but I'm assuming this is where something must have gone wrong.
2. Tried to add async to my SQLite functions (ended up removing it).
3. Added Stack navigation in App.tsx.

[image]
[image]

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VeB4.png)

Comment: The error states that you're using two packages for `masked-view` in your project. So please add `package.json` so that we can check.

Comment: I've just added that and yes there are 2 packages. I uninstalled one of them and my app was working again does that mean I cannot use both together? :/

Comment: Yes, both of them target same value in AndroidManifest.xml.